# Speeding up this query? Currently it takes 4 seconds on 100K rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This is my main query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'set arithabort off;set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;Select COUNT(*) From ( Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                                (Order By  Case When d.OldInstrumentID IS NULL THEN d.LastStatusChangedDateTime Else d.RecordingDateTime End desc ) peta_rn,    
                                d.DocumentID
                                From Documents d
                                Inner Join Users u on d.UserID = u.UserID Inner Join IGroupes ig on ig.IGroupID = d.IGroupID
                                Inner Join ITypes it on it.ITypeID = d.ITypeID Where 1=1  ANd dbo.DoesNameExist(d.DocumentID, @0, @1, @2, @3) = 1  And (CreatedByAccountID = @4 
                                Or DocumentStatusID = @5
                                 Or DocumentStatusID = @6 ) )
                                  v',N'@0 int,@1 varchar(4000),@2 varchar(4000),@3 nvarchar(4000),@4 int,@5 int,@6 int',@0=-999,@1='K',@2='Miller',
                                  @3=NULL,@4=44,@5=5,@6=9
```

and this is my scalar function which is the **culprit**:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DoesNameExist]
(
    @DocumentID         int,
    @PartyTypeID        int = 0,
    @FirstName          varchar(30),
    @LastName           varchar(30),
    @Business           varchar(100)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @Found bit = 0

    Set @FirstName = IsNull(@FirstName,'')
    Set @LastName = IsNull(@LastName,'')
    Set @Business = IsNull(@Business,'')


    Select Top 1 @Found = 1
        From DocumentNames
            Where DocumentID = @DocumentID
                    And
                Lower(IsNull(FirstName,'')) Like 
                            Case When @FirstName = '' Then  Lower(IsNull(FirstName,'')) + '%'
                                Else Lower(@FirstName) + '%' End
                    And
                Lower(IsNull(LastName,'')) Like 
                            Case When @LastName = '' Then   Lower(IsNull(LastName,'')) + '%'
                                Else Lower(@LastName) + '%' End
                    And
                Lower(IsNull(Business,'')) Like 
                            Case When @Business = '' Then  Lower(IsNull(Business,'')) + '%'
                                Else Lower(@Business) + '%' End

                    And

                PartyTypeID = Case When @PartyTypeID IS NULL OR @PartyTypeID <= 0 Then PartyTypeID Else @PartyTypeID End


    Return @Found
END
```

Basically one document has multiple DocumentNames and when the user types something in LastName or FirstName, I want to bring the count of all documents which have those matching names. Please note, I am querying on Documents table and then joining to DocumentNames. This is necessary.

**Note:** Indexes are created on all search columns which include FirstName, LastName etc.

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you move the function body into the main SQL statement? Usually the UDFs are the culprits, as the engine cannot optimise the performance and ends up doing full table scan

Comment: @cha: I appreciate the suggestion. However, how can I move it inside SQL statement?

Comment: Can you clarify - your first SQL just returns a COUNT, not a list of documents. From a brief look at what you've done, it looks like you could get a substantial improvement if you used IF EXISTS rather than calling your function, since it seems to be doing just that.

Comment: In other words replace `dbo.DoesNameExist(d.DocumentID, @0, @1, @2, @3) = 1` with `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (a reproduction of your function)`

Comment: I suspect the EXTREMELY poor quality of your DoesNameExist function is giving the optimizer fits. Try rewriting it in about 1/2, or even 1/3, as many characters; ie, really think about what whay you have so many unnecessary conversions and comparisons and conditions in it.

Comment: @Pieter: I have no idea why you feel it is poor? I have FirstName, LastName and BusinessName. When user passes either of the name, I have to search in all the DocumentNames for that particular Document. How else would write this?

Comment: (1) in many cases your conditions reduce to a field self-test like this: Lower(IsNull(FirstName,''))  = Lower(IsNull(FirstName,'')), but mangled so the optimizer cannot do its job.

Comment: @ElectricLama: Could you please post your answer?

Comment: @Pieter: Could you post your anwer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check `Execution plan`.
 How may times `IsNULL()` is getting used?
Check estimated and actual time taken for all `IsNULL()`. If it is more, use a subquery where you can just calculate `IsNULL()` and supply to your query.

I do not have your `Exceution plan`. You can also **try this aswell** :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DoesNameExist]
(
    @DocumentID         int,
    @PartyTypeID        int = 0,
    @FirstName          varchar(30),
    @LastName           varchar(30),
    @Business           varchar(100)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @Found bit = 0

    Select Top 1 @Found = 1
        From DocumentNames
            Where DocumentID = @DocumentID
                    And
                Lower(IsNull(FirstName,'')) Like COALESCE(@FirstName,firstname,'')+'%'
                    And
                Lower(IsNull(LastName,'')) Like COALESCE(@LastName,LastName,'')+'%'
                    And
                Lower(IsNull(Business,'')) Like COALESCE(@Business,Business,'')+'%'

                    And

                PartyTypeID = Case When @PartyTypeID IS NULL OR @PartyTypeID <= 0 Then PartyTypeID Else @PartyTypeID End


    Return @Found
END
```

Also if you are ok to discard this `UDF`, using this directly in your statement with `EXISTS` clause should do the trick.

```
Select COUNT(*) From ( Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                                (Order By  Case When d.OldInstrumentID IS NULL THEN d.LastStatusChangedDateTime Else d.RecordingDateTime End desc ) peta_rn,    
                                d.DocumentID
                                From Documents d
                                Inner Join Users u on d.UserID = u.UserID Inner Join IGroupes ig on ig.IGroupID = d.IGroupID
                                Inner Join ITypes it on it.ITypeID = d.ITypeID Where 1=1  



                                ANd EXISTS (
                                Select 1
                                From DocumentNames
                                    Where DocumentID = d.DocumentID
                                            And
                                        Lower(IsNull(FirstName,'')) Like COALESCE(@1,lower(firstname),'')+'%'
                                            And
                                        Lower(IsNull(LastName,'')) Like COALESCE(@2,lower(LastName),'')+'%'
                                            And
                                        Lower(IsNull(Business,'')) Like COALESCE(@3,lower(Business),'')+'%'

                                            And

                                        PartyTypeID = Case When @0 IS NULL OR @0 <= 0 Then PartyTypeID Else @0 End




                                )



                                Or DocumentStatusID = @5
                                 Or DocumentStatusID = @6 ) )
                                  v',N'@0 int,@1 varchar(4000),@2 varchar(4000),@3 nvarchar(4000),@4 int,@5 int,@6 int',@0=-999,@1='K',@2='Miller',
                                  @3=NULL,@4=44,@5=5,@6=9
```

Comment: What do you mean by your last statement? *using this directly in your statement with EXISTS clause should do the trick.*. Any sample?

Comment: How can I write If exists within a sql statement without using UDF function?

Comment: Wahh Ravi Wahh!! You did the trick man. Awesome!! Now it gets executed in 0 seconds.

Comment: @Jack, You can find the exact time that the query takes, in milliseconds, using `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` and `OFF`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx.